# Link two polygon records

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, link

So I have one feature class with many different polygons in it with different xy coordinates, different shapes, and different records all in the same attribute table. Some polygons share common attribute data. For example, the first polygon may be a circle around a fire hydrant and the other polygon may be a rectangle of the sidewalk that the fire hydrant is on. They both have different records but are in the same feature class' attribute table. I want to set it up so that if an end user clicks on the fire hydrant polygon the sidewalk polygon will also be highlighted. So when the attribute table is opened if one record is highlighted the other record is too.

**Here are the two polygons:**

[image]

**Here are their attribute data:**

[image]

So what I would like to do is make it so that when an end user selects the large polygon only, or the small polygon only, two things happen:

1. both polygons are highlighted, and
2. both records are selected in the attribute table

Any way to do this in ArcGIS Pro?

**Update:**

Here are the two selected polygons and the attribute tables:
[image]

The HC_id filed is a text, length 12. Here is the tool, parameters, and script:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but like you said the records merge. So I get two polygons and one record in one feature class. I am trying to make it so the records AND the polygons are separate, all in one feature class. Simply put, when you select one polygon in the map it highlights the other polygon as well. Then, when you open the attribute table with maybe 4,000 records and click on Show Selected Records, both records for both polygons show.

Comment: My terminology may be off a bit. I updated my post to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Same project number. I didn't include that field in the image. I can link them somehow via a project number?

Comment: I know it can be queried in Select by Attributes, but I am thinking more if someone selects the polygon in the map with the select tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way* to do this just by clicking on a feature (with the select tool).  However, it can be fairly easily achieved by running a Python script in a script tool after selecting the polygon.

First, click on the feature (or multiple features), then run the tool.  The tool will then select all other features in the same layer that have the same value(s) as the selected feature(s) for the attribute you choose.

I have confirmed that this works using the following script:

```py
import arcpy

layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fieldName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
idList = []

if not len(arcpy.Describe(layer).FIDSet):
    arcpy.AddWarning("No features are selected")
    exit()

matchedFields = arcpy.ListFields(layer, fieldName)
if not len(matchedFields):
    arcpy.AddWarning("Specified field does not exist in that layer")
    exit()
    
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,[fieldName]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        idList.append(row[0])

if matchedFields[0].type == "String":
    where = "{} IN ('".format(fieldName) + "', '".join(idList) + "')"
else:
    where = "{} IN (".format(fieldName) + ", ".join(idList) + ")"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, where_clause=where)
```

Here's how I configure the parameters of the script tool:

[image]

You can hard code the layer and field names, if you wish, either in the script itself, or as defaults in the script tool.  (I did the latter, as it is more flexible, but hard-coding into the script and removing the tool parameters would make it simpler if you are certain you will never need to run it against any other layer or with any other attribute.)

Here's how the script tool looks when I open it, ready to run:

[image]

*Actually, I believe that a single step click-on-a-polygon method could be achieved by building an Add-In, however, since ESRI no longer support Python Add-Ins, building Add-Ins is no longer a simple thing to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I added the tool in Catalog, added the same parameters but it is only selecting one polygon with the Select tool when I run it. Also I didn't modify your code, it was just cut and paste. The field I want to use is titled HC_id. So do I input HC_id in (field) in line 8? Thanks!

Comment: I changed line 8 but it failed. It's in the code I think.

Comment: Hmm. When I select two polygons from the attribute table and then input that feature layer into the Input Layer field it runs but doesn't do anything. When I don't select any records and input the feature layer into the Input Layer field it just selects all the records.  When I clear the selections after I run the tool and then click on a polygon it only highlights that polygon and its record in the attribute table, but not the polygon I was trying to relate it to.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Let me change that.

Comment: I just updated the image in my original question.

Comment: But still same problem when I run it with the most recent code you posted. I run the tool, hit Clear in the Selection tab in the Ribbon, and click on one of the two polygons. It only chooses the polygon and its accompanying record i the attribute that I select, but still doesn't select the other polygon I'm trying to relate it to.

Comment: You need to run the tool **AFTER** selecting (clicking on) a polygon. As the answer says, "First, click on the feature... then run the tool".  Sorry if this wasn't clear.  Note that the tool does NOT cause other features to become selected when you click on a feature.  It causes other features to become selected when you run the tool (based on which features are already selected/clicked-on before the tool was run).  I don't think there is any way to do this just by clicking on a feature.

Comment: Yep, that worked that's great! Now, how can I make it so it is automatic when I click on a polygon? Simply, if I am looking at a map with 4,000 polygons all in one feature class and I click on one polygon that is a part of project HC50125, but there are three other polygons out there with project numbers HC50125, how will all 4 polygons will show up in the attribute table when I click on Show Selected Records? This is because a user may not know there are other polygons out there with the same project number.

Comment: As I stated at the beginning of this answer, I don't think it's possible in a single (one-click) step. I think that this script tool may be the nearest thing you can get. It's a two step process... click on the polygon, then run the tool. Want to do it for another polygon? Click on the other polygon, then run the tool.  (Actually, I think the single-step just click-on-a-polygon concept could be done with an Add-In, but these are not in the realm of ordinary GIS users since ESRI no longer support Pyton Add-Ins.

Comment: @TheOmoSlide if you want a tool that interacts with the map, you need to expose a new parameter as a FeatureSet. This will allow you to draw a geometry (e.g. a simple rectangle) and that would feed into your code which would do a select by location and that selection feeds into SonofaBeach's code for relating the selection. Personally that would be a bit of a faff, I would do what SonofaBeach is suggesting, make a selection first then run the code. You could always put in a check for a selection and bail out if none exists?

Comment: Looks like it is too difficult. Thanks for your help on this though.